# How to get network access AWS VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking

I have a non-private AWS VPC built on a Centos 7 image, however I am unable to to a yum update. Can you help me troubleshoot how I can get connection to the outside network to do updates and downloads?

here what I have to see so far:

```
command:  echo $https_proxy
http://172.2x.xx.xx:8080


command: $ sudo yum -y update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Could not get metalink https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-7&arch=x86_64 error was
14: curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 2620:52:3:1:dead:beef:cafe:fed6: Network is unreachable"
 * base: centos.host-engine.com
 * epel: fedora.mirrors.pair.com
 * extras: linux.cc.lehigh.edu
 * updates: centos.mirrors.tds.net
http://centos.s.uw.edu/centos/7.7.1908/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 2607:4000:200:4a::38: Network is unreachable"
Trying other mirror.
http://centos.host-engine.com/7.7.1908/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 2001:49f0:d064:5::2: Network is unreachable"
Trying other mirror.
http://mirror.centos.iad1.serverforge.org/7.7.1908/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://mirror.centos.iad1.serverforge.org/7.7.1908/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Connection timed out after 30001 milliseconds')
Trying other mirror.
http://mirror.mobap.edu/centos/7.7.1908/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#7 - "Failed connect to mirror.mobap.edu:80; Operation now in progress"
Trying other mirror.
```

Comment: Is this Amazon EC2 instance in a public subnet, or a private subnet? How have you connected to it (directly, or via a bastion, or a VPN connection)? Why have you configured a proxy? Do you get a result if you `curl google.com` from the instance?

Answer (score 0):

Private VPC does not have internet access.

To enable internet access need to setup [internet gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html) and make one of your subnets public. Instances in that subnet will be able to access internet and be accessible from the internet.

If your instances are in a private subnet, and you want your instances to have internet access, but not be accessible form internet, then have to setup [NAT gateway or NAT instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat.html).